# Xampp vs Firebase for large scale quiz app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, xampp

I am creating an android quiz app, the core features of the app are

1. database user registration and login(registering a minimum of 100k users)
2. several databases(about 10) for different quiz categories holding about 500k+ questions in total to be retrieved by the user only when there is an internet connection on the android device

i need the app to be really secure as it would also be using credit card information

my question here is which would be better for the database,
using xampp(php, mysql and apache) or using google firebase? and why?

and is having 10 databases for 10 diffrent categories efficient, or can i have one database for the 10 categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. xampp is fully own your dedicated server, so you will need monitoring 
 and execute everytime whenever you need to do.Very need time for adding new feature next.

firebase is public server you can use free maintenance and troubleshoot. much feature their offer.push notif,authentification and etc.and it safe and secure for business.for further information you can visit firebase console site,

2nd. 10 database for 10 categories. it mean 1 database for 1 categories. you can call your database based your user request.

conclusion : it depending your technical skill and your exeperience to choosing an online service. if you try develop an app earn money. dont forget put an Ads space. so you can earn money for it.